# When kaliyuga will end then yuga cycle again rotate to Sat-yuga then what will happen, like Shree Râmaji take avatâr again?

Tags: krishna, rama, yuga, kali-yuga

As we are living in the `Kaliyuga` when it will become end then again yuga cycle rotate to Sat-yuga. Then my question is that then there will be same leelâ of my god like they will take avatâr of Lord Râma, Lord Křishňa in their respective yuga? Please resolve my curiosity.

Comment: Lord Rama, Lord Krishna.. etc.. won't take birth in every Treta, Every Dwapara.. for example recent Ramavatar was in 24th Treta while recent Krishnavatar was in 28th Dwapar.. we are in 28th Kali now.. various forces should match to take Lord to take avatars like various boons, karmic links etc.. Though avatars take birth multiple times.. for example Lord Rama was born in past several times before the recent appearance.. but it is not like in every Treta Lord Rama will come...

Comment: Okay sir thank you very much for info @Tezz Hare Krishna

Comment: @Tezz One more question is that Kaliyuga had happened many times before ? If it had happened then which avatar of lord krishna taken birth. Sorry to bother you.Again thank you Sir